# How would one say 'passing a buck' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

or equivalently 'shift the responsibility'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Briefly: *reĵeti responson* or *malakcepti kulpecon* or *pasigi la akuzon*.

Some other ideas:

- *Li nur ĵetas la propran respondecon aliulen.* He just throws his own responsibility onto other people.
- *Li tajlas por aliaj la propran kulpecon.* He tailors for others his own guilt.
- *Ŝi glitigas sian krimon en poŝon de alia.* She slips her crime into another's pocket.
- *Ŝi enterigas la kadavron en la ĝardeno de sia najbaro.* She buries the body in the garden of her neighbour.